# Which storage interface for a laptop solid state disk, and which model of SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, pci-express

I want to replace my laptop hdd with an ssd.

I was headed for the 1TB samsung 850 pro sata but it cost a lot of bucks.

So if I have to spend so much money I want to buy a disk that i will reuse in my next laptop or desktop. Maybe i can use it in my current laptop with an adapter (my laptop has only sata connections)

There are a lot of standard interface for ssd:

- Sata
- mSata
- M.2

Which one should i choose to be future compliant?

UPDATE---

My question is about an investment also for future use. I want to buy 1tb ssd with an interface that i can reuse when maybe next year i will change laptop.
clearly having top performance like with an m.2 ssd

My laptop accepts sata 3 disk

Don't say adpater does not fills in laptop because there are tons of adapter with 2,5 form factor

Comment: M.2 is the newest standard and replaces mSATA, if that is what you are asking.  Otherwise, what you use would be what your laptop supports.

Comment: I never said an adapter didn't exist, I just said, for your purposes it cannot be used.  I have deleted my comments.

Comment: Since you are thinking of getting new hardware next year I suggest you use the SATA 3 interface. This is currently the most used interface and this trend is likely to be kept for the next few years.

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD - SATA 3 is on the way out.  In a few years most high-end storage devices will only support M.2 because of bandwidth requirements.  SATA 3 will remain for optical drives and mechanical storage devices ( provided they are produced ) by the time motherboards start to really support M.2.

Comment: SATA 3 will almost certainly still be well supported a year from now. You'll have no difficulty using a SATA 3 SSD. However, M.2 will probably be the preferred format in a year. If you're considering a SATA 3 SSD and an equally fast M.2 SSD, it won't much matter. But if you're considering a much faster M.2 SSD, you may appreciate that next year, even if the SATA 3 adapter prevents you from getting that extra speed for a year.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you take the point of my question! my dubt is about m.2 sata or m.2 pcie. as far as i know m.2pcie is faster and can become the future standard but it is not possible to have a sata/m.2pcie adapter

Comment: @Ramhound M.2 is a physical format and can use either a PCIe, SATA (or USB) interface, and it has replaced the mSATA/mini-PCIe physical format.

Comment: If your current laptop has an M.2 slot that only supports SATA, as you seem to be implying, your only choice is to get an M.2/SATA SSD.  If your next laptop supports M.2/PCIe for SSDs, you could still use your SSD, but getting a new one would get more performance.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of "future compliance" a SATA-based SSD would most likely be the best choice for you. SATA is presently the most commonly used standard for data devices in the consumer world, and as such the accompanying SSDs are also the least expensive for what you get.

I would recommend the following SSDs based on their performance and price, as well as trusted reliability.

- Crucial M500 (960GB) - sales as low as $170-$180
- Samsung 850 EVO (1TB) - sales as low as $300-$310

The 850 EVO is going to be the much faster of the two, but the M500 will still run laps in orders of magnitude around a mechanical or "traditional" disk. I did not recommend the Samsung 850 "PRO" because it comes at an additional tax for no real consumer benefit.

---

Is is important to note that if you only ever plan to use your SSD in a laptop, that the M2 or mSata ports could have some added value for their low profile. Do note that these options generally have less options and less cross-compatibility with their desktop counterparts, which use the typical 2.5" SSDs you are accustomed to seeing.

Comment: For the 850 at 1TB, there is almost no performance difference between the EVO and the PRO. This is not true for other model lines (such as the 840) and other sizes (such as 500GB). There's pretty much no reason to pay more for the PRO.

Comment: I haven't been able to find the 850 PRO, 1TB capacity for less than $400 on the best of sales thus far. At $300 the EVO easily makes up for the performance difference. http://slickdeals.net/newsearch.php?q=850+pro+1tb&searcharea=deals&searchin=first

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the one your laptop supports.

Comment: Technically, this is an answer.  You could have made it even shorter by leaving off "You should choose".  Since there is insufficient information for a specific answer, you might have considered posting this Zen response as a comment.  Just sayin'.

Comment: my laptop support sata so with an adapter i can put msata and some m.2 (not sure) disk

Comment: @fixer1234 I think putting answers in as comments is almost as disruptive as putting comments in as answers. My hope was to avoid low quality answered consisting mostly of shopping recommendations and actually answer the question asked. My plan was sabotaged by a change to the question that made it a much better question, however, it still doesn't have a proper answer.